# Sleeping awaiting command in sql

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vb6

What is the cause for sleeping and awaiting commands in sql. It is happening randomly not for a particular queries. Actualy we are using vb and classical asp for our application. When the sleeping status process reach in and around 700 DB get hanged and itself goes to sleep mode.Please advice the reason for causing this kind of error...

Answer (score 0):

Connection pooling keeps your connections open to avoid the quite expensive overhead of actually connecting every time.

Not sure what you mean by "Hanging" or ""sleep mode" but are you using SQL Server Express? Autoclose? Not much RAM? Hard to say without more information

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are using sql server 2005. And i mentioned about sleep mode know that is Database goes to sleep  mode when status sleeping awaiting command reached in and around 700 records and my question is any other reason is for such a error.

Comment: A database *cannot* go into sleep mode

Comment: @gbn I think they may be referring to process state in SQL Server, sleeping processes is normal nothing to worry about. It just means the process is idle.